# Android: Gradually increase the volume of a notification sound

Tags: android

I have a notification which I would like to increase the sound gradually until it is dismissed/answered. How could I do this? Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I performed this task. First I capture the originally settings. After graduating the and once the user dismisses the notification I call another function to return the settings. Here is the code for graduating the sound:

```
 public static void graduateVolumeLevel(Context context) {
    getVolumeLevel(context);
    final AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    final int DELAY_UNTIL_NEXT_INCREASE = 6 * 1000;

    LaunchService.startThread();

    mHandlerIncreaseVolume = new Handler(appService.thread.getLooper()); 
   /*you may not need this part.
    I use it b/c i run my stuff on another thread not to 
   interfere with the main thread. 
   Creating a new handler on main thread may be sufficient for your needs.*/

   if(runnable==null) {
       runnable = new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               int currentSystemVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM);
               int currentRingVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);

               if (currentSystemVolume != mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM)||
                       currentRingVolume != mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING)) { //if not max
                   //increase the volume of the alarm stream 
                   mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,currentRingVolume++,0);
                   mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, currentRingVolume++, 0);

                   if(mHandlerIncreaseVolume!=null)
                   mHandlerIncreaseVolume.postDelayed(this, DELAY_UNTIL_NEXT_INCREASE);
               }
           }
       };
   }

    mHandlerIncreaseVolume.post(runnable);
}
```

I found a similar posting but couldn't found it again to reference it. It is what I used to create my code, with slight modification by me, because the example didn't work exactly as is. Also once I return the original settings I remove callbacks from the handler and set it to null.